# Bind ASP.net object fails on test server, but not dev

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error for an item in a GridView:
**A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind.
**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkColumn" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select"
        Text='<%# Bind("TableName.Column") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

I can't work out why it works fine on my dev server, but not on the test machine.  It also works on the production box?  We are running ASP.NET 3.5 for the website.

Comment: One of these dupes needs to be deleted...

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate :- deleted

Comment: @Anthony should've deleted this one, since it's marked as the duplicate and flagged to close!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  The test server was the only one without .NET 3.5 SP1.  I installed the SP and rebooted - problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being rude: Is it worth double checking your database schema, looking for a missing field? Is anything different between your environments? Try using winmerge to compare your environments (its great!)

Another idea: comment out the 'bind' row, and replace it with these, to get a better idea what's going on:

```
<%= Table.Field %> 
<%= Table.Field.GetType().ToString() %> 
<%= Table.GetType().ToString() %>
```

Comment: Schemas are the same - database is a restored version of the test server db.  Website on test is the Published version,so no significant differences in files.

Comment: How about try my other new suggestion above then?

Answer (score 1):

Noticed 2 instances of .net 3.5 SP1 in "Programs and Features" in windows 2008 SP1 server. Uninstalled (which removed both items), restarted, reinstalled .net 3.5 SP1 again (which this time appeared as one instance in the list. Everything worked fine, no more bind errors.